# Iterate through Object keys to return true value only

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, boolean

Problem instructions: Write a function displayOptions which receives an object "displayDevice", and returns an array. The input object's properties will be "video output" options, each of which will either have a true or false value. Your function should collect all the "video output" names which have true values.

I figured out a way to do this problem using the .filter() method, however, I don't fully understand that and wanted to try to do this using a for..in statement. I'm able to iterate through the object, but it's returning all keys in the array, and not just the "true" ones. Let me know where I went wrong here.

My Code:

```js
function displayOptions(displayDevice) {
  for(var key in displayDevice) {
    if(displayDevice[key] === true) {
      return Object.keys(displayDevice);
    }
  }
}

var televisionA = {
  VGA: false,
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true
}
var monitor001 = {
  VGA: true,
  DVI: false,
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true
}
var monitor002 = {
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true,
  DVI: true
}

displayOptions(televisionA); //["HDMI1", "HDMI2"];
displayOptions(monitor001); //["VGA", "HDMI1", "HDMI2"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are returning all the objects keys when you found the first `key` with a `true` value (give a read to what [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) does). In my opinion, you need to create a new array and push the keys on it when a `true` value is found.

```js
function displayOptions(displayDevice)
{
    let newObj = [];

    for (var key in displayDevice)
    {
        if (displayDevice[key] === true) // or just if (displayDevice[key])
            newObj.push(key);
    }

    return newObj;
}

var televisionA = {
  VGA: false,
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true
}
var monitor001 = {
  VGA: true,
  DVI: false,
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true
}
var monitor002 = {
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true,
  DVI: true
}

console.log(displayOptions(televisionA)); // ["HDMI1", "HDMI2"];
console.log(displayOptions(monitor001));  // ["VGA", "HDMI1", "HDMI2"];
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense! Just tried it and it worked :D thank you - also your explanation helped a ton! I know that .filter() is easier to do but I want to make sure I was understanding how I was getting there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.keys to get the keys and filter them according to true/false

```js
var televisionA = {
  VGA: false,
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true
}
var monitor001 = {
  VGA: true,
  DVI: false,
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true
}
var monitor002 = {
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true,
  DVI: true
}
console.log(Object.keys(televisionA).filter((e)=>televisionA[e]))
console.log(Object.keys(monitor001).filter((e)=>monitor001[e]))
console.log(Object.keys(monitor002).filter((e)=>monitor002[e]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to `filter`:

```js
function displayOptions(displayDevice) {
  return Object.entries(displayDevice).filter(([, bool]) => bool).map(e => e[0]);
}

var televisionA = {
  VGA: false,
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true
}
var monitor001 = {
  VGA: true,
  DVI: false,
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true
}
var monitor002 = {
  HDMI1: true,
  HDMI2: true,
  DVI: true
}

console.log(displayOptions(televisionA));
console.log(displayOptions(monitor001));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, since I didn't see in the replies, another alternative can be `reduce`:

```
const displayOptions = displayDevice =>
  Object.entries(displayDevice)
    .reduce((acc, [key, val]) => (val && acc.push(key), acc),[]);
```